# Phaser (3.24.1) How to tween a TileSprite?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, tween

I would like to tween a TileSprite by tilePositionX and tilePositionY.

```js
scene.load.image('sky', 'assets/images/sky.png');
const sky = scene.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 1000, 600, 'sky');
scene.add.tween(sky); // "Uncaught TypeError: n is null"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples [1](https://labs.phaser.io/view.html?src=src%5Ctweens%5Cnumber%20tween.js) [2](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/tween)

```js
scene.tweens.add({
    targets: sky,
    tilePositionY: { from: 0, to: -180 },
    ease: 'Linear',
    duration: 5000,
    repeat: 0,
    yoyo: false
});
```

Comment: You should be able to mark your own answer as the accepted answer, FYI.